# Graph dfs-related code passes almost all test cases, fails on a few

Tags: python, dictionary, memory-management, runtime-error, depth-first-search

I have a following problem and corresponding code:

You have a rectangular field of size NxM. You have K marked cells. N,M,K and marked cells coordinates are read from an input file. Two marked cells are considered adjacent if they share a side. The task is to compute the number of connected components and write it to an output file.

The following code passes almost all test cases and runs on all cases I came up with on repl.it, but gives runtime-error in the automated checking system. I can't really access what the error is.

```
with open("input.txt") as f:
    inp = f.readlines()

line1 = list(map(int, inp[0].strip().split()))
N = line1[0]
M = line1[1]
K = line1[2]

#represent marked cells as a dictionary, key = cells, value = list of marked neighbors
dict_ = {tuple(map(int, x.strip().split())): [] for x in inp[1:]}

#collect neighbors
def get_neighbors(idx):
    i = idx[0]
    j = idx[1]
    ans = [(i - 1, j), (i + 1, j), (i, j - 1), (i, j + 1)]
    return ans

#add them to the graph
def add_neighbors(idx):
    neighbors = get_neighbors(idx)
    dict_[idx] = [x for x in neighbors if x in dict_.keys()]  # return(None)


def dfs_recursive(graph, vertex, visited, path):
    visited[vertex] = True
    path.append(vertex)
    for neighbor in graph[vertex]:
        if not visited[neighbor]:
            path = dfs_recursive(graph, neighbor, visited, path)
    return path


def conn_comps(graph):
    visited = {vertex: False for vertex in graph}
    comps = []
    for vertex in graph:
        if not visited[vertex]:
            path = []
            v_path = dfs_recursive(graph, vertex, visited, path)
            comps.append(v_path)

    return comps

#populate neighbors
for idx in dict_.keys():
    add_neighbors(idx)

ans = len(conn_comps(dict_))


FOUT = open("output.txt", "w")
FOUT.write(str(ans))
FOUT.close()
```

My only guess is the problem with dict size - K can be as high as 10^5 by definition, N,M up to 10^5 as well. Can someone comment and suggest other improvements? This a practice problem from an old intro-level contest.

Comment: can you post "input.txt"? so it will be easier to run this code

Comment: it's run against many test cases, and I don't have access to the one it fails on, unfortunately.  the case where it does work, is e.g. '2 2 2'  '1 2' '2 1' (each string on a separate line), with the answer 2 (two components)

Comment: can you link to the original question if you may?

Comment: The original link and screenshot I have is in Russian only. But what I posted is more or less a direct translation minus some fluff (i.e. they do not directly say you need to compute connected components, but you can easily infer it). The gist is you read three numbers N, M, K from the first line and then you have K lines of two integers each, which are the marked cells coordinates. Marked cells are considered adjacent by side (but not corners).

Comment: ok, let me try debugging your code, thanks

Comment: thank you for you help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone finds this - you just hit python's default recursion limit of 1000. Need to either rewrite iteratively or increase it manually `sys.setrecursionlimit`. Alas.